# Returning the Territory Model name and Territory Name based on Account ID

Tags: apex, soql, territory-management

I am trying to populate a custom field on my account object called "Original Territory" that tracks the value of a territory name from the associated Territory2 record.

I am trying to create a trigger and am stuck on the SOQL I need to write to return the value for both fields. I have multiple Territory2Models and need to validate that its the current active model, I want to return the value of the territory name and the state of the related territory model, but I keep getting an error when using this query:

```
String accountId; //the accountId that will be passed

List<Territory2> territories = 
      [SELECT Name, 
          (SELECT State FROM Territory2Model WHERE Id = Territory2ModelId) 
       FROM Territory2 WHERE Id IN (
            SELECT Territory2Id FROM ObjectTerritory2Association
            WHERE ObjectId = :accountId)
       ];';
```

Comment: you look like you have  spurious trailing `';`

Comment: What is the exact error text?